# Booststrap table insert break after modulus

Tags: html, templates, html-table, bootstrap-4

What should I change in my code in order to have only 3 columns?

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Start</th>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
    </tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

edit: here is the real code (data from Django). I dont know in advance the number of rows.

```
  {% for pi, coll in items %}
<strong>{{pi}}</strong>
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Start</th>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
    </tr>
  {% for element in coll %}
      <td>{{element.Collocation.StartDate}} at {{element.Collocation.StartTime}}</td>
      <td>{{element.Type}}</td>
      <td><a href="{% url 'event_collections:detail' element.pk %}"> {{element.Title}}</a></td>
  {% endfor %}
    </thead>
  </table>
```

This is what I have

[image: snap]

Comment: Just add `tr` start tag after `for` loop and add `tr` end tag before `endfor`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have  tag for each row.
The  tag defines a row in an HTML table.

> Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

```html
<table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Start</th>
          <th scope="col">Type</th>
          <th scope="col">Title</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>32</td>
          <td>33</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

**Dynamic Rows for the Table**

```
  <?php  foreach($rows as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$row['Price'];?></td>
            <td><?=$row['Year'];?></td>
            <td><?=$row['Value'];?></td>
        </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: I've edited my code. The thing is I don't know the amount of raws in advance

Comment: @saikuron You will need to use foreach if that is the case. I updated my answer.
Also check this stackoverflow.com/a/9821501/9999127

Answer (score -1):

Please Add this kind of structure.

```html
  <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Start</th>
          <th scope="col">Type</th>
          <th scope="col">Title</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>31</td>
          <td>32</td>
          <td>33</td>
       </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
  <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Start</th>
          <th scope="col">Type</th>
          <th scope="col">Title</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>11</td>
       <td>12</td>
       <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
      </table>
```

I think this should work check it out.